# Как установить ПО на HDD диск на Mac OS

Tags: mac

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки нового SSD диска, не возможно установить Adobe Photoshop, ниже прикрепил скрин сто выдает, как можно установить на HDD (ssd чувствительный к регистру, поэтому не даёт установку)

Comment: "ssd чувствительный к регистру, поэтому не даёт установку" - ерунда полнейшая! К регистру чувствительна файловая система, а не диск. И уж совершенно точно не устанавливается не из-за этого.

Comment: Где сообщение об ошибке? Нужно добавить информацию, что значит "невозможно установить", как это проявляется?